# Calculate zoom level of tiles

Tags: math

I'm trying to calculate a variable based on a zoom level.

For example I have a 4x4 grid of tiles at zoom level 1. Now I zoom in once it will become 8 * 8 at zoom level 2. Zoom in once again and it will be 16 * 16 at zoom level 3. etc.

Now the only thing I store are the two numbers from zoom level 1 which can change to for example 5x4 or even 1x1.

So my question is how do I calculate the width and height of zoom level's 2 and 3 and beyond with just those two numbers and the zoom level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you always doubling the sides on each zoom level? You need to describe better what zoom level 2 and 3 look like.

Comment: Zoom level 4 should become 32 * 32 that is if zoom level 1 is 4x4. If zoom level 1 where 5x4 it would become 40 * 32. Zoom Levels 2, 3, 4, etc. should be somehow calculated from zoom level 1.

Comment: Are you writing this for a particular language? C++, Java, etc.  It sounds to me you're just doubling each side per level, so a `for` loop will work, but it's difficult to give an exact solution without more information.

Comment: I'm writing this for JavaScript. But since most of the languages have the same math operators it shouldn't be too hard to convert if a example where given in C++.

Comment: 2 raised to the power of zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slicker way of doing the same thing is to use bit shifting since you're always multiplying by a power of 2 with each zoom level.

```
var x = this.data.Size.X;
var y = this.data.Size.Y;

x = x << (zoom-1);
y = y << (zoom-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jmstoker I've figured out how to get it working properly

```
var x = this.data.Size.X;
var y = this.data.Size.Y;
for (var i = 1; i < zoom; i++) {
    x += x;
    y += y;
}
```

I just get the count of tiles on each side and go through the amount of zoom levels excluding level 1 and adding the count to itself for each zoom level.